# PHP: Its 20 minutes past midnight and somehow on refresh the php date doesnt change. Why is the php god angry on me?

Tags: php

As i said before, its 20 min past midnight, and when i do check the date using php

as date("Y-m-d");
and date("Y-m-d",strtotime("now"));

i still get the previous days' date. I expected a lot of things to go wrong while coding but definitely not this. I wouldnt even have it in the list of potential-things-that-could-go-wrong. I have refereshed the browser, using SHift + refresh and have also gone to the extent of restarting the system.

What went wrong?

Comment: The PHP god is angry at the choice of namespace separators in 5.3.  Oh wait... no, that's just me ;)

Comment: So how do i please the PHP god? teach me the ritual.

Comment: damn it must be the time zone just figurng out how to change that.. where do i do that? apache ? php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you get the correct time? I.e. print more info:

```
echo date("c")
```

This will give you everything, date, time, time zone etc.

You can set the timezone you want to use with [date_default_timezone_set](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php). You can find a list of [valid timezones here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

You can also set a timezone in your php.ini config by setting the [*date.timezone*-directive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php).

Comment: 2009-09-07T19:07:38+00:00 this is what i get. T

Comment: if i use date(strtotime) i get 4230Mon, 07 Sep 2009 19:08:42 +0000302009300809UTC

Comment: Looks like it is running GMT time

Comment: oops i added my own answer before i refreshed the page... thanks machine

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure the server runs on the same time zone as you're expecting?

Try printing out the actual time as well and see if that tells you anything.

Answer (score 1):

Is the timezone on the server set properly? How about the [timezone for PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)?

Comment: I am using php at my home computer, with apache. Is setting the time zone necessary?

Comment: Yes, it must be set in php.ini or with date_default_timezone_set(), as otherwise PHP must guess and emits a notice.

Answer (score 0):

The date doesn't change on subsequent refreshes, or the date didn't change on midnight (from `2009-09-06` to `2009-09-07`)?

Answer (score 0):

yup all you folks are right.. it was a problem with the timezone. changed it by adding uncommenting the ;date.timezone property in php.ini and adding the required timezone as given in http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php. Thanks guys